# Ubuntu isn't using 4-cores

Tags: 14.04, cpu

My notebook processor has 4 physical cores. but ubuntu is showing only 2 of them. what can i do to make ubuntu use all the cores?

```
$ sudo lshw -C cpu

*-cpu                   
   description: CPU
   product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
   vendor: Intel Corp.
   physical id: 2b
   bus info: cpu@0
   version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
   serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
   slot: U3E1
   size: 1867MHz
   capacity: 1867MHz
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 100MHz
   capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cpufreq
   configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4

$ nproc
 4
```

info from /proc/cpuinfo

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 69
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x16
cpu MHz     : 2376.281
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 4788.76
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 1
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 69
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x16
cpu MHz     : 2752.593
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 1
initial apicid  : 1
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 4788.76
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 2
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 69
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x16
cpu MHz     : 2446.125
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 2
initial apicid  : 2
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 4788.76
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:

processor   : 3
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 69
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4500U CPU @ 1.80GHz
stepping    : 1
microcode   : 0x16
cpu MHz     : 2132.718
cache size  : 4096 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 4
core id     : 1
cpu cores   : 2
apicid      : 3
initial apicid  : 3
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc aperfmperf eagerfpu pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm ida arat epb xsaveopt pln pts dtherm tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid
bogomips    : 4788.76
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

Comment: What processor do you have? What are you using to show the cores?

Comment: Please edit your post and add the output of `sudo lshw -C cpu` and `nproc`.

Comment: If available, the content of `/proc/cpuinfo` may also provide valuable info.

Answer (score 3):

Your processor is not a quad-core, it's a dual-core with Hyper-Threading: [Intel.com: ARK | Intel® Core™ i7-4500U Processor (4M Cache, up to 3.00 GHz)](http://ark.intel.com/products/75460/Intel-Core-i7-4500U-Processor-4M-Cache-up-to-3_00-GHz).

Accordingly, `sudo lshw -C cpu` tells this as well:

```
configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 threads=4
```

This means that the processor has two physical cores, but each physical core is virtualized from Intel's Hyper-Threading Technology into 2 logical cores so that the system is capable to handle four thread at the time instead of two. From [Wikipedia.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-threading):

> Architecturally, a processor with Hyper-Threading Technology consists of two logical processors per core, each of which has its own processor architectural state.

And that explains things like the fact that you detect four cores instead of two for example in `System Monitor`.

Comment: Note: This is a similar case with my system - Intel Core i7-3632QM (Laptop CPU) @ 2.20GHz - `configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=8` - `htop` shows '8' CPUs, but it's really 4 cores with hyperthreading, and 8 is just the illusion (4 cores, 2 threads each).  So this isn't abnormal.  :)  (just supporting your answer, kos)